# Is it possible to attach a PDF to user notifications in Freeform Pro

Tags: solspace-freeform, file-uploads

Is it possible to send a user notification with a pdf attached to users who fill in a form via Freeform Pro?

It would be the same pdf for every user (terms and conditions for a site i'm working on)

I thought a way round it might be to have it as a hidden field on the form and create a file upload field within that form. As I can see that it is possible to add attachments to the user notification if any files are uploaded when the form is submitted. But the problem would be that forms would take a little longer to submit for the user and I'd end up with potentially hundreds of copies of the pdf on the system.

Could anyone offer any advice or solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do this but you can approach it in a different way which would probably be less problematic in the long run too.

PDFs really bulk up the size of email and are a highly ranked trigger for spam filters. Because of this, you'd most likely end up with delivery problems.

Since you say the PDF would be the same for all users, a different, and possibly better solution, would be to include a link to the PDF which would be hosted on your site somewhere (it can be hidden away). That way you aren't sending a comparatively large file in a small email and thus running less risk of tripping a filter.

A second approach might be to simply include the T&Cs as text within the email. Is there a specific reason it needs to be a PDF?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your advice. I had the same thought about using a link to the pdf instead. And I thin you're right that is probably the best option. Thank you.